# List Index Out of Range when using PDF Plumber

Tags: python, pdfplumber

Hello I am extracting text from PDF using pdf plumber and writing it to a text file but I am getting index out of range error.

`````
import glob
import pdfplumber



for filename in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
    pdf = pdfplumber.open(filename)
    OutputFile = filename.replace('.pdf','.txt')
    fx2=open(OutputFile, "a+")
    for i in range(0,10000,1):
        try:
            page = pdf.pages[0]
            text = page.extract_text()
            print(text)
            fx2.write(text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    fx2.close()
    pdf.close() ````
`````

Comment: `for i in range(0,10000,1):` what is purpose of this loop? why are during exactly same thing in each turn regardless of `i` value?

Comment: I am trying to get the text out of every page, it works for some pdf and I guess when the loop returns back it is not recognizing the index value, that is what my understanding is but I may be wrong, that is why I sought help

Comment: please add `print(len(pdf.pages))` immediately before `page = pdf.pages[0]` and run your code. Check and write if that `print` does output `0` for some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
filename = 'path/to/your/PDF'
crop_coords = [x0, top, x1, bottom]
text = ''
pages = []
with pdfplumber.open(filename) as pdf:
    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        my_width = page.width
        my_height = page.height
        # Crop pages
        my_bbox = (crop_coords[0]*float(my_width), crop_coords[1]*float(my_height), crop_coords[2]*float(my_width), crop_coords[3]*float(my_height))
        page_crop = page.crop(bbox=my_bbox)
        text = text+str(page_crop.extract_text())
        pages.append(page_crop)
```

`crop_coords` is a list used for cropping you page.
Here is the explanation of coordinates:

```
x0 = % Distance from left vertical cut to left side of page.
top = % Distance from upper horizontal cut to upper side of page.
x1 = % Distance from right vertical cut to right side of page.
bottom = % Distance from lower horizontal cut to lower side of page.
```

If you don't want to perform that, just use the following code:

```
filename = 'path/to/your/PDF'
text = ''
pages = []
with pdfplumber.open(filename) as pdf:
    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        text = text+str(page.extract_text())
        pages.append(page)
```

In both cases, the results will be:

- `text`: string containing all the text of your PDF
- `pages`: a list where every element is the object page. You can access its
  properties, look [here](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#the-pdfplumberpage-class)